# Django non persistent model field

Tags: python, django

I have a Django Model where I create an random password for the user.

**Manager.py:**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, password=None):
        user = self.model()

        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
        else:
            user.set_password(user.generate_password())
        user.save()
        return user
```

I then want to send out an email to the user with their temporary password after the model is saved.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def registration_email(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        pass
```

My problem is that the password is hashed (which is good) so I cannot do the following in the `post_save` function... `instance.password`. So is there a way I can have a non persistent model field to read from (just on this first save) i.e. `instance.tempcleartext`. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as-is, you can grab a reference to the password before you set it:

```
self.temp_pw = user.generate_password()
user.set_password(self.temp_pw)
```

And then you have access to the password as self.temp_pw but it will be a volatile property, not one that gets saved to the db.

HOWEVER, I would strongly recommend against doing this and particularly against sending passwords by email. It is far better to provide a password reset feature, IMO.

Comment: Possibly "self" is not the right instance, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: +1 in the "HOWEVER" note... OP should check out https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ where this problem has already been solved robustly